# Proving whether a predicate proposistion is valid under all interpretations?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Is the sentence:

$(∃xQ(x)∧∃xR(x))           →                  ∃x(Q(x)∧R(x))$

valid?

(Where $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ are predicates and $x$ is the set of real numbers)

If it is explain why. If it isn't, give an interpretation under which it is false.

How do I know which interpretations could be false for this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your domain of interpretation is the set $\mathbb{R}$ of reals. Now, interpret $Q(x)$ as "$x \geq 0$", and $R(x)$ as "$x < 0$". What can you conclude?

Clearly, $\exists x Q(x) \land \exists xR(x) \, $ is *true* under this interpretation, because there exists a non-negative real number (e.g. $1$) and there exists a negative real number (e.g. $-1$).

On the contrary, $\exists x (Q(x) \land R(x)) \, $ is *false* under the above interpretation, because there is no real number that is at the same time non-negative and negative.

Therefore, the sentence $(\exists x Q(x) \land \exists x R(x)) \to \exists x (Q(x) \land R(x)) \, $  is *false* under the above interpretation, since the antecedent (i.e. the left-hand side) of the implication is true but the consequent (i.e. the right-hand side) is false.

Comment: The sentence would be false under this interpretation? On both sides of the implication? Since x greater than zero and x less than zero don't ever intersect.
Is there a difference between the left side interpretation of the implication and right side interpretation of the implication?
How would I explain it in words?

Comment: @Tanster - Please, see my last edit. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now!
:)

Comment: @Tanster since you are new. .. If this Answer  answers your question to your satisfaction, it is customary to accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Interpret $Q(x)$ as '$x$ is positive' and $R(x)$ as '$x$ is negative'

Comment: Heck, even simply $Q(x)$ iff $x=1$ and $R(x)$ iff $x=0$. Then clearly $((\exists x~x=1)\wedge(\exists x~x=0))$ but not $\exists x~(x=1\wedge x=0)$